# WPF Access grid items onClick

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm new to wpf and have what I hope is a simple question.

I have created a simple template to display some grouped items

Currently when I click on one of the items ItemsClick is called (as expected)

```
    private void itemGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        MyCustomClass selectedItem = (MyCustomClass)e.ClickedItem;
        GridView g = (GridView)sender;
```

I can get a copy of the class object by casting e.ClickedItem and the grid from sender. But what I don't see is how to I get a reference to the custom items I added in the template for example if I wanted to change the text in the testName TextBlock ?

Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTestTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" Stretch="Fill" Width="175" Height="175" />
                </Border>
                <Image Source="{Binding MyCustomImage}" Height="30" Width="30" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,0,0,30"/>
                <Grid x:Name="ItemDetails" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Height="75" Margin="0,0,0,2" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="testName" Text="{Binding Name}"  Grid.Row="0" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"  Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource 

CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                     </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>


<GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,137,40,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTestTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="True"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
            RightTapped="itemGridView_RightTapped" 
            ItemClick="itemGridView_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="itemGridView_SelectionChanged">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                                <Button
                                    AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding state}"/>
                                     </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </GridView.GroupStyle>
        </GridView>
```

Comment: Your code shows the item bindings, but not the binding for the collection.  Can you include that also?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer on msdn.

The link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx

The basic steps

get the selected item (I was responding to click so this info was easy), find the ContentPresenter within that Item, and then call FindName on the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter.